# Correct term for "Cabin Window"?

Tags: terminology, architecture

Like the ones in a:

- cinema ticket selling point
- purge contention chamber (sci-fi)
- reception point of a public institution
- police control point

(where one can attend someone else, behind a security glass)

Comment: Information, Ticket Booth, Reception, Consierge, Processing, and Incoming are a few that come to mind. You might be able to search for others by brainstorming here... https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/ticket_booth.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'kiosk' is the first word that springs to mind

Other words depending on the case are:

- stand
- stall
- counter
- booth